# Take ID´s and put them into a anker navigation with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got a special problem. On my "one page" site, I've split the content into several div, e.g. "Agenda", "Event", "Location" and so on. I need a JavaScript that generates from that ID´s a navigation, like this:

### HTML

```
 <div class="navi">
        <ul>
            <li><a >Item 1 (Suppost to be Agenda)</a></li>
            <li><a >Item 2 (Suppost to be Event)</a></li>
            <li><a >Item 3 (Suppost to be Location)</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="Agenda">
            Content item 1
        </div>
        <div id="Event">
            Content item 2
        </div>     
        <div id="Location">
            Content item 3
        </div>
        
    </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RDFf9/1/

But I don´t know how.

Comment: Have you tried anything with jQuery so far?

Comment: You should rather ask such question on freelancer.com. people are here to help, not for doing everything.

Comment: I´m starting with jQuery right now, thats why im not so firm with all the possibilities. Its only for my own little Blog and I´m trying it with learning by doing.^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fairly easy:

1. Loop over all items you want to have a menu entry listed for
2. For each of these items, add an entry in your menu

I've updated your [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RDFf9/7/) with a vanilla JavaScript example, but you could work out how this would work in jQuery.

This is the JavaScript:

```
var menu = document.getElementById("nav");
var contentContainer = document.getElementById("content")
var contentEntries = contentContainer.children;

for(var i = 0; i < contentEntries.length; i++){
    var menuEntry = document.createElement("li");
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.innerText = contentEntries[i].id;
    menuEntry.appendChild(link);
    menu.appendChild(menuEntry);    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use following;

```
$("#content div").each(function() {
   $(".navi ul").append('<li><a href="#'+ $(this).attr("id") + '">' + $(this).attr("id") + '</a></li>');
});
```

Here is a working demo: **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RDFf9/4/)**

Comment: Might this be better `$(".navi ul").append('<li><a href="#' + $(this).attr("id") +'">' + $(this).attr("id") + '</a></li>');`

Comment: It is like as yours in demo but I forgot to add in my answer

Comment: This is AWESOME! :) Is it possible that the script only generates a navpoint, if the div got a clss called"nav"?
Like so: http://jsfiddle.net/RDFf9/8/